# jquery typeahead set static first element and then order asc the others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem which I can't figure out. I'm using jquery typeahead from runningcoder (http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/), and I'm trying to set a static first element that is always the first one, and then the other elements with asc order.

My code is the following:

```
$.typeahead({
        input: ".js-typeahead",
        minLength: 0,
        maxItem: false,
        order: "asc",
        emptyTemplate: '<span class="text-muted">Nessun paese corrisponde a <strong>{{query}}</strong></span>',
        searchOnFocus: true,
        source: {
            groupName: {
                // Ajax Request
                ajax: {
                    url: "../wp-json/shipping-data/available-countries",
                    callback: {
                        done: function (data) {
                            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                                data[index] = SUtils.lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters(value);
                            });
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        debug: true
    });
```

I'm trying to put the country Italy as first element suggested in the list, but I can't achieve this since the directive "order: asc" is reordering the data array. How I can have "order: asc" but with Italy as the first element in list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have your complete implementation, this is my guess from your snippet. Basically you will have to find the element (in this case with `Italy`), then put it to the first of the array, and fill the array with other items. Something like this:

```
done: function (data) {
  const sortedData = $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    data[index] = SUtils.lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters(value);
  });
  sortedData = [
    sortedData.find(item => item == 'Italy'), //find item which is 'Italy'
    ...sortedData.filter(item => item != 'Italy') //spread operation to fill the array with the rest of the items which are not `Italy`
  ];
  return sortedData;
}
```